# How to move a java script to a custom file then call it from MVC app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to move a script (that opens a modal window), from inside the view into a custom script file, but I need some help with it.

This is part of the Index view:

```
<div class="">
    <button id="showModal">Click Me</button>
</div>

div id="theModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       // Code
       ...
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var showModal = function () {
                $("#theModal").modal("show");
            };
            $("#showModal").click(showModal);
        });
    </script>
}
```

I know that I need to hoop up the function in the button OnClick event and add a reference to the script file, but the question is: What is the correct way to write the script as a function in the file, pass the arguments and how to properly call it from the click button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged MVC 4 so I assume you will use the bundler.

First make sure the script file you created is in a bundle, look for `BundleConfig.cs`
and add a bundle for your new file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myBundle").Include(
  "~/Scripts/sample.js"));
```

Then in your view:

```
@Scripts.Render(
    "~/bundles/myBundle")
```

Here is the requested concrete example:

Assume a file called `sample.js` with the following content:

```
showAlert = function(){
     alert('hey an alert!);
};
```

In your view:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#showModal').on('click', function () {
        showAlert();
    });
});
</script>
```

This will add `showAlert` as the event handler for the click of the showModal anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in your external javascript file (and referencing it in your view), will ensure the click handler gets set on the button. [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#showModal').on('click', function () {
        $("#theModal").modal("show");
    });
});
```

What type of arguments did you want to pass to this event? What do you want to get back from it?